# Outbound IP for Python Azure Function - requests IP not match list of function outbound IP

Tags: python, azure, networking, azure-functions

I ve created Python function on Azure that call external API service which allows to access only for whitelisted IPs.

Based on Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses) I found all OutboundIPAddresses and PossibleOutboundAddresses and whitelisted all of them. Despite of IPs have been whitelisted I keep receiving 403 Forrbiden error from the service.

I also verified IP address of the request by adding following code to the function:

`ip = requests.request('GET','https://api.ipify.org').text` 
`logging.info('Request send from IP: {}'.format(ip))`

It seems that actual outbound IP address is diffrend then specified on the OutboundIPAddress and PossibleOutboundAddresses lists.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are there other forms of authentication or is it open for the selected IPs?

Comment: There are also user:password authentication, however if user or password is incorrect service returns another error code (function app works properly with service stage env where endpoint does not require whitelisting). I asked provider to verify logs of the service - turns out that requests send from function app have random IP addresses.

Comment: Switch to a dedicated App Service Plan, that one has deterministic outbound IP assignment. However this IP filtering thing is very brittal in the cloud, i wouldn't touch it. Instead, either use OAuth to authenticate your function to the endpoint it's calling (client credentials flow maybe), or use something static like a secret stored in App Settings that you send via an HTTP header. You then check the header's value and if it passes validation you process the request.

Answer (score 0):

Per our documentation

> When a function app that runs on the Consumption plan or the Premium
> plan is scaled, a new range of outbound IP addresses may be assigned.
> When running on either of these plans, you may need to add the entire
> data center to an allowlist.

If you need to add the outbound IP addresses used by your function apps to an allowlist, another option is to add the function apps' data center (Azure region) to an allowlist. You can [download a JSON file that lists IP addresses for all Azure data centers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). Then find the JSON fragment that applies to the region that your function app runs in.

Comment: I did that and I see there are over a hundred IPs for my region.  Do all of these IPs have to be added to the whitelist? That's very poor solution :(((